# php to mysql data retrieval

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from mysql database that has 4 rows. I need to send this as an table in email using php. I have built a script for this, but the issue is the script is not emailing all the rows, its just emailing the last row or if i pass a specific parameter with "where" in db query.

Any help from anyone is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Attached the db output and php code as well.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$today = date("j-F-Y g:i:s a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm


// DB Connect.
$db_host = 'localhost'; // Server Name
$db_user = 'root'; // Username
$db_pass = 'test123#'; // Password
$db_name = 'util'; // Database Name

 $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
        if (!$conn) {
                die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        $sql = "select * from srvr1";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (!$result) {
                die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
        }

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                $File_system = $row[0];
                                $IP = $row[1];
                                $Capacity = $row[2];
                                $Available = $row[3];
                                $Used = $row[4];
                                $Percentage = $row[5];

                # Compare Percentage and alert.
                $subject = "Critical | FH NetApp-NetBackup Space Utilization..!";
                    $message1 = "
                    <html>
                        <body>
                            <p> Hi Team,<br><br>  The Server utilization is <b style='color:red'> critical</b>. Please find the below utilization details.</p>

                                                        <table>
                                <tr>
                                        <th> File_System </th>
                                        <th> IP </th>
                                        <th> Total_capacity </th>
                                        <th> Available_Capacity </th>
                                        <th> Used_Capacity </th>
                                        <th> Percentage </th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td> $File_system </td>
                                        <td> $IP </td>
                                        <td> $Capacity </td>
                                        <td> $Available </td>
                                        <td> $Used </td>
                                        <td> $Percentage </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            <p style='font-size:15px'> Data generated at:<b> $today EST.</b><p>
                            <p>Regards, <br>
                               Backup Team. </p>
                        </body>
                </html>";
                    $headers[] = 'From: Srvr19utilization@util.com'; // Sender's Email
                    $headers[] = 'Cc: santosh.kowshik20@gmail.com'; // Carbon copy to Sender
                    $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0 charset=".$encoding."';
                    $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
                    // Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
                    $message = wordwrap($message1, 70);

                    // Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
                    mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
        }
}
?>
```

[image]

I have been trying to shuffle around the loop in the code, it did not help.

Comment: Do a `var_dump` on your `$result` variable before the loop. What's actually in there? i.e `var_dump($result);`

Comment: @ElroyJetson

Below is the output i get once i added var_dump.
```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(6)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(1)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and rearrange your code a little bit. First create the 'top' of the html, then go through all the results and append them to the html and then finish the html.

I haven't tested the code beneath but it should work :-)

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$today = date("j-F-Y g:i:s a"); // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm


// DB Connect.
$db_host = 'localhost'; // Server Name
$db_user = 'root'; // Username
$db_pass = 'test123#'; // Password
$db_name = 'util'; // Database Name

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
    die('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql    = "select * from srvr1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$result) {
    die('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $subject = "Critical | FH NetApp-NetBackup Space Utilization..!";
    $message1 = "
          <html>
              <body>
                  <p> Hi Team,<br><br>  The Server utilization is <b style='color:red'> critical</b>. Please find the below utilization details.</p>

                                              <table>
                      <tr>
                              <th> File_System </th>
                              <th> IP </th>
                              <th> Total_capacity </th>
                              <th> Available_Capacity </th>
                              <th> Used_Capacity </th>
                              <th> Percentage </th>
                      </tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $File_system = $row[0];
        $IP          = $row[1];
        $Capacity    = $row[2];
        $Available   = $row[3];
        $Used        = $row[4];
        $Percentage  = $row[5];

        # Compare Percentage and alert.
        $message1 .= "
                                <tr>
                                        <td> $File_system </td>
                                        <td> $IP </td>
                                        <td> $Capacity </td>
                                        <td> $Available </td>
                                        <td> $Used </td>
                                        <td> $Percentage </td>
                                </tr>";
    }
    $message1 .= "</table>";
    $message1 .= "<p style='font-size:15px'> Data generated at:<b> $today EST.</b><p>
                                <p>Regards, <br>
                                   Backup Team. </p>
                            </body>
                    </html>";

    $headers[] = 'From: Srvr19utilization@util.com'; // Sender's Email
    $headers[] = 'Cc: santosh.kowshik20@gmail.com'; // Carbon copy to Sender
    $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0 charset=".$encoding."';
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
    // Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
    $message   = wordwrap($message1, 70);

    // Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
    mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));

}
?>
```

About conditional formatting

No worries. You can try and use nested ternaries (shorthand for if/else... to keep it short :-))

Example snippet from above code:

```
...
$Percentage  = $row[5];
$color = ($Percentage > 90) ? '#FCE901' : (($Percentage > 85) ? '#FF0000' : '#00E526');
# Compare Percentage and alert.
$message1 .= "
                        <tr>
                                <td> $File_system </td>
                                <td> $IP </td>
                                <td> $Capacity </td>
                                <td> $Available </td>
                                <td> $Used </td>
                                <td style=\"background-color:$color\"> $Percentage </td>
                        </tr>";
```

Comment: Sorry to get this here. I am trying to do a conditional formatting on $Percentage on the table when i send email. Any suggestion on how to achieve that? I have tried with javascript did not go well, i tried inline css did go well either.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is somewhere on your database end. Based on your `var_dump` output:

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(6) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

You only have 1 result being returned. You should start there. Maybe you're not referencing the table you think you are. Who knows right now, but you `php` looks fine. Investigate your DB

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP is not fine stubben gave you the answer

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$today = date("j-F-Y g:i:s a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm


// DB Connect.
$db_host = 'localhost'; // Server Name
$db_user = 'root'; // Username
$db_pass = 'test123#'; // Password
$db_name = 'util'; // Database Name

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) 
{
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "select * from srvr1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$result) 
{
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $File_system = $row[0];
        $IP = $row[1];
        $Capacity = $row[2];
        $Available = $row[3];
        $Used = $row[4];
        $Percentage = $row[5];
```

---

***Above You have a Percentage from 1 Row of Data
Below you use that to decide the eMail subject - only 1 subject per email - so 1 row of data per email***

---

```
        # Compare Percentage and alert.
        if($Percentage > 90)
        {
            $subject = "Critical | FH NetApp-NetBackup Space Utilization..!";
            $message1 = "
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <style>
                            body,h6 {
                                font-family: Segoe UI,Helvetica,courier;
                            }
                            th {
                                border: 1px solid black;
                                border-collapse: collapse;
                                background-color: #04D1E8;
                                padding: 10px;
                                text-align: center;
                            }
                            td {
                                border: 1px solid black;
                                border-collapse: collapse;
                                padding: 10px;
                                text-align: center;
                            }
                            .cri {
                                background-color: #FF0000;
                            }
                        </style>
                    </head>

                    <body>
                        <p> Hi Team,<br><br>  The Server utilization is <b style='color:red'> critical</b>. Please find the below utilization details.</p>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th> File_System </th>
                                <th> IP </th>
                                <th> Total_capacity </th>
                                <th> Available_Capacity </th>
                                <th> Used_Capacity </th>
                                <th> Percentage </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> $File_system </td>
                                <td> $IP </td>
                                <td> $Capacity </td>
                                <td> $Available </td>
                                <td> $Used </td>
                                <td class='cri'> $Percentage </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <p style='font-size:15px'> Data generated at:<b> $today EST.</b><p>
                        <p>
                            Regards, <br>
                            Backup Team. 
                        </p>
                    </body>
                </html>
            ";

            $headers[] = 'From: Srvr19utilization@util.com'; // Sender's Email
            $headers[] = 'Cc: santosh.kowshik20@gmail.com'; // Carbon copy to Sender
            $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0 charset=".$encoding."';
            $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
            // Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
            $message = wordwrap($message1, 70);

            // Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
            mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
        } 
        else if($Percentage > 85)
        {
            $subject = "Warning | FH NetApp-NetBackup Space Utilization..!";
            $message1 = "
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <style>
                            body,h6{
                                font-family: Segoe UI,Helvetica,courier;
                            }
                            th {
                                border: 1px solid black;
                                border-collapse: collapse;
                                background-color: #04D1E8;
                                padding: 10px;
                                text-align: center;
                            }
                            td {
                                border: 1px solid black;
                                border-collapse: collapse;
                                padding: 10px;
                                text-align: center;
                            }
                            .war {
                                background-color: #FCE901;
                            }
                        </style>
                    </head>

                    <body>
                        <p> Hi Team,<br><br>  The Server utilization is <b style='color:yellow'> above normal</b>. Please find the below utilization details.</p>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th> File_System </th>
                                <th> IP </th>
                                <th> Total_capacity </th>
                                <th> Available_Capacity </th>
                                <th> Used_Capacity </th>
                                <th> Percentage </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> $File_system </td>
                                <td> $IP </td>
                                <td> $Capacity </td>
                                <td> $Available </td>
                                <td> $Used </td>
                                <td class='war'> $Percentage </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <p style='font-size:15px'> Data generated at:<b> $today EST.</b></p>
                        <p>
                            Regards, <br>
                            Backup Team. 
                        </p>
                    </body>
                </html>
            ";

            $headers[] = 'From: Srvr19utilization@util.com'; // Sender's Email
            $headers[] = 'Cc: santosh.kowshik20@gmail.com'; // Carbon copy to Sender
            $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0 charset=".$encoding."';
            $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
            // Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
            $message = wordwrap($message1, 70);

            // Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
            mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
        } 
        else 
        {
            $subject = "Normal | FH NetApp-NetBackup Space Utilization..!";
            $message1 = "
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <style>
                            body,h6{
                                font-family: Segoe UI,Helvetica,courier;
                            }
                            th {
                                border: 1px solid black;
                                border-collapse: collapse;
                                background-color: #04D1E8;
                                padding: 10px;
                                text-align: center;
                            }
                            td {
                                border: 1px solid black;
                                border-collapse: collapse;
                                padding: 10px;
                                text-align: center;
                            }
                            .nor {
                                background-color: #00E526;
                            }
                        </style>
                    </head>

                    <body>
                        <p> Hi Team,<br><br> The Server utilization is <b style='color:green'> normal. </b>Please find the below utilization details.</p>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th> File_System </th>
                                <th> IP </th>
                                <th> Total_capacity </th>
                                <th> Available_Capacity </th>
                                <th> Used_Capacity </th>
                                <th> Percentage </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> $File_system </td>
                                <td> $IP </td>
                                <td> $Capacity </td>
                                <td> $Available </td>
                                <td> $Used </td>
                                <td class='nor'> $Percentage </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <p style='font-size:15px'> Data generated at:<b> $today EST.</b></p>
                        <p>
                            Regards, <br>
                            Backup Team. 
                        </p>
                    </body>
                </html>
            ";
            $headers[] = 'From: Srvr19utilization@util.com'; // Sender's Email
            $headers[] = 'Cc: santosh.kowshik20@gmail.com'; // Carbon copy to Sender
            $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0 charset=".$encoding."';
            $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

            // Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
            $message = wordwrap($message1, 70);

            // Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
            mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The size of his query is only 1 before he does ***anything*** based on his `var_dump`. How does `$percentage` have anything to do with this. My assumption of course is that (s)he put the var_dump immediately after the query lol.

Comment: @Elroy Jetson I'm not saying his/her data is Ok just saying the PHP isn't - it is structured to produce a single email from a single data record. As stubben said needs to write headers and subject line etc first then a series of table rows for each data record, but the percentage field determines the email subject - as code is currently written :-)

Comment: ahh, understood.